# Algorithm to calculate referenced formulas only once

Tags: php, algorithm, formula

i am looking for a nice algorithm to solve the following problem.

I have the following listing of VARIABLES and FORMULAS (result of var is the sum of all formulas):

```
var1, result=10
  - 5+5=10

var2, result=15
  - var1+5

var3, result=30
  - var1+var2+5
```

now i am looking for a nice way to calculate all references. if i am changing var1 and the result is 15 now, i have to calculate all referenced to var1. first i came across var2 and recalc var2, if the result of var2 changed i have to recalc all referenced formulas to var2. therefore i would recalc var3 twice (var2 changed, var1 changed)...

is there any solution to not calc var3 twice in this scenario?

thx!

Comment: of course var3 is 30... just typed that out of my head and forget to calc var1 into the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ensure you recalculate each variable only once (at most), by using the fact that there are no cyclic dependencies (no way a variable `x` needs `y` in order to be calculated, and in the same time `y` also needs `x`).

This is done by modeling the problem as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)), where all variables are vertices, and a "needed" relation is a directed edge. (So, if variable `x` "needs" variable `y` to be calculated, there is an edge `(y,x)`).

Now, since the No-Cyclic dependency, this is actually a [Directed Acyclic Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), which you can do [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) (This can be done only once in pre-processing). Note that it is very possible that in your case, the graph is already sorted, sine it is given as a chronological sequence of events, and the chronological order is a topological sort.

Do a topological sort on the graph (if needed), and whenever variables are changed:

```
Upon variable change:
1. Mark all changed variables
2. From first variable to last (according to topological sort), for each variable x:
      2.1. If there is some dependency `(y,x)` on the graph such that `y` is marked:
           2.1.1. mark x
           2.1.2. recalculate x
```

It is easy to see that each variable is calculated at most once according to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of variables/formulas that needs to be recalculated. Using this list you can see whether all dependencies are up-to-date or not.
If this is not the case, you should postpone updating the variable.

Going back to your example and lets say `var1` changes.

First step is to put `var` in the list and check all depending variables/formulas. These are `var2` and `var3`, so put them in the list as well.

Next check the depending variables/formulas of `var2` (as you put it in the list as well), this is `var3`, it is already in the list, so leave it. Last check `var3` (you added it as well), nothing is depending on `var3` so you are done. (Note the recursive behavior!)

The second step is to update your values. So find a variable/formula that has all its dependencies. Only `var1` has not dependencies, so pop it from the list and calculate its value.

Next find another variable/formula in the list, `var3` is still depending on `var2` (which is  still/also in the list), so only `var2` is suitable to process.
Therefore pop `var2` from the list and calculate its value.

Continue processing the list, until it is empty.

Assuming you do not have circular dependencies: Everything is calculated only once!